# generating a random string from regex in typescript

Tags: javascript, regex

My function currently generates a random string consisting of numbers, uppercase and lowercase letters.

```
/**
 * generate random string
 * @param {number} length
 * @returns {string}
 */
static generateRandomString(length: number): string {
    return Math.random()
        .toString(36)
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '')
        .substr(0, length);
}
```

I would like it to generate only capital letters and numbers.
I did it but it doesn't work:

```
  .replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/g, '')
```

Comment: `.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/g, '')` will replace any character matched by the expression with `''` or in other words it will delete all of the letters and numbers. You probably just want to call `.toUpperCase()` instead of replace.

Answer (score 0):

That's a hell of a way to make random strings.

The `number#toString(36)` will make it so that you get values from 0 to z which doesn't include capital letters. Here's a way to fix it by just using the `string#toUpperCase` method to convert lowercase to uppercase.

```
/**
 * generate random string
 */
function generateRandomString(length: number): string {
    return Math.random()
        .toString(36)
        //.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, '') // Regex isn't necessary here
        .replace('.','') // There's only ever one non [a-z0-9] character in this
        .toUpperCase()
        .substr(0, length);
}
```

Here's another way to do it that allows you to properly control the length and helps make sure that the random characters are closer to being truly random. Note there is no need for a regex here.

```
/**
 * generate random string
 */
function generateRandomString(length:number): string {
  return new Array(length)
    .fill(0)
    .map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 36).toString(36))
    .join('')
    .toUpperCase();
}
```